# How to properly lock access to a List in multiple Threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, list, thread-safety, locking

I have a List that I am adding values to, every *interval* seconds, which is running in a thread.

```
var point = GetPoint(presentValue);
DataSource[itemIndex].Add(point);
```

In an Event I then read values from that List, to be exact I search for the closest value to my target. I Create a local variable for that list to work with, but sometimes I get the Exception

"**Destination array not long enough**" when creating this List.

I've figured out that this must mean the List was changed while the new List was created, so it's got something to do with the Code above. After a bit of research I found about thread-safety and the "**lock**" keyword, which I then tried to use. I tried locking to the list itself, to the list's SyncRoot and to a custom sync object, but the error still occured.

```
lock (SyncHelper.TrendDataPointLock)
{
    var point = GetPoint(presentValue);
    DataSource[itemIndex].Add(point);
}
```

and

```
lock (SyncHelper.TrendDataPointLock)
{
    points = new List<DataPoint>(ActualPoints);
}
```

I know that I'm not fully familiar with the aspects of thread safety, but after looking at many different approaches I still can't seem to make this work.

1: Any advice on how to fix my error

2: Do I need to have a lock statement on every access of that list in order to be sure that the thread will pause before the other lock is released?

3: If not 2, then does locking to the list itself, make every thread block, no matter if they also have a lock statement around the list access or not? So locking on the *Add* statement "should" fix my problem.

EDIT: 
`DataSource`is a `Dictionary<int, List<DataPoint>>`
`ActualPoints`is a reference to the list `DataSource[itemIndex]`
The only place where I Edit this list is in the Code above, and when I clear the list.

the `points`variable is only there for accessing certain indexes to find the closest value to my target, but the index is always lower than `points.Count`, to be exact, binary search thought the list so im starting in the middle.   The Application only crashes when accessing `ActualPoints` to create the `points` list, so everything after that shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: You should use a `lock()` every time you use the List to ensure that it is thread safe. You can create an object that you use for locking. Use this object only and on every occasion: `private object lockObject = new object();`.
When locking: `lock(lockObject) {  ...  }`

Comment: (1) In general it is exactly what Stefan says, but I think we need to see a bit more to be sure. I am not clear where you set itemIndex, or where else you might use points for example. (2) yes (3) only the code in the all the {}'s for the same object is locked

Comment: How is `DataSource` defined? Is it `public List<DataPoint> DataSource` by any chance? If so, no amount of locking is going to make this threadsafe, since any other thread can access the list without going through the lock.

Comment: @MatthewWatson DataSource is actually a `public Dictionary<int, List<DataPoint>> DataSource { get; set; }` and im setting the ItemSource of a list (which is the list that i edit) to `ItemsSource = _dataSource[itemSourceIndex]`. DataSource is only used in its origin class so far though, so i could actually make it private. The list of 'ItemsSource' is then used (but not edited) in other classes.

Comment: @Catoffel Making that public is risky. Not only can anything modify the dictionary, anything could modify the lists in the dictionary too.

Comment: Since you are using this list as data source for a UI element, it is probably safer to avoid updating the list from any other thread than the UI thread. Otherwise you may indirectly cause the UI element to be accessed by a non UI thread, which is illegal and can cause obscure errors. I suggest that you enforce this limitation, at least on the debug builds of your app, by setting the property [`Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.checkforillegalcrossthreadcalls) to `true` before `Application.Run`.

Answer (score -1):

Try a collection which is already threadsafe. Check out [Thread-Safe Collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/).